# Current_user method using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've just started to use devise today and I want to know if I have to create a current user method in my application controller or is it already created through devise ?

Comment: Devise defines `current_user` as helper method so you can use it both in your controllers and templates.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Devise creates that helper method for you, and others too. Check

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers