# Use Devise current_user to make new record with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a new record in my create method.

Users have many apartments.

When I run this code, I receive this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `apartments' for nil:NilClass): `create'
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
class ApartmentsController < ApplicationController

# skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

def index
    @user = User.all
    @apartments = Apartment.all
    render :json => @apartments, :include => :user
end

def create
    # apartment = Apartment.create
    # render json: apartment

    @apartment = current_user.apartments.build(params[:apartment])
end

def apartment_params
    params.require(:apartment).permit(:street_name)
end
```

end

This is my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :authenticate_user!
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  protected_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :phone, :hours])
end
```

end

I've looked at other similar posts, but not seem to solve the issue.

The solution at this post did not provide a solution:
[Current_user method using devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003792/current-user-method-using-devise)

Answer (score 1):

This should be help if you change:

> @apartment = current_user.apartments.build(params[:apartment])

for this:

> @apartment = current_user.apartments.create!(params[:apartment])